How to download file using Spring boot Http Interface client
I want to use HttpExchage in my upcoming project. I read many articles for HTTP interface clients. Everywhere the Object was returned as part of the return type. I want to use upload and download files via HTTP Interface. Is there any way to upload/download the file?
interface RepositoryService {

    @GetExchange("/repos/{owner}/{repo}")
    Repository getRepository(@PathVariable String owner, @PathVariable String repo);

    // more HTTP exchange methods...

}


Use the same classes as you would use in the controller methods for upload and download, namely Resource and MultipartFile.
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.service.annotation.GetExchange;
import org.springframework.web.service.annotation.PostExchange;

interface MyClient {

  @GetExchange("/download")
  Resource download();

  @PostExchange("/upload")
  ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file);

}

